# Facebook auto creating a new Fan Page for every site page that I have open graph tags on that gets liked?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a web app that has pages with the facebook OG meta tags on them as they are objects for some open graph actions. I noticed in testing that when a user "A" "likes" one of those pages, that behind the scenes facebook is creating a new facebook specific page as a sort of "copy" of my original page. Then when user"A's" friends (let's say user "B") sees that "liked" page on their news feed, and click on it, it takes them to `facebook.com/pages/<og:title>/randomnumber` instead of to the original source, `www.mysite.com/some_page_that_got_liked`.

As the admin of the facebook app, if I click on it, I see the fb page with the admin panel, so I can administer it...but I lose all that potential direct traffic to my site. It seems like FB is stealing traffic from under me.

Anyone know if there is a way around this?

Thanks in advance,
Chad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm, seems as though this magically stopped. Gotta love that.

Comment: I think it might have to do with this, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/25/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: @CBroe, yep and you can read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/